# Global variable in nanoc

Tags: ruby, global-variables, nanoc

I'm building a site with nanoc and cannot find out how to use a global variable that could be incremented on the compilation of each page. The idea behind this is to get the list of all tags (incrementing the appearance number each time a tag is seen).

I though that declaring the variable in `lib/helper.rb` would do the trick, but it's not working that way.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in fact, I just had to declare $my_var in lib/helpers.rb. This var is then accessible in all pages during compilation.
Luc